# is it faster to cudaHostRegister a moving address range or copy into a fixed Registered range

Tags: cuda

Is it faster to cudaHostRegister a moving address range (window) or copy into a fixed Registered address range?
cudaHostRegister pins host memory (makes pageable memory unpageable) to accelerate transfer from host to device memory.  One can register a range of host memory, then transfer, then register another range, etc.  Or, alternatively, one can register a single range of host memory, copy into that range and transfer, then repeat the process with a second data set without re-registering the address range.

Comment: Given that the toolkit chooses to copy into a buffer that is probably the faster way. But why not give it a try and benchmark for yourself?

Comment: In my experience, creating a pool of registered memory and re-using it proved to be a lot faster than registering a new memory for every copy. As an example, I used this approach to process a video stream where every frame had to be uploaded to the GPU, so I just registered a memory space for initial frame only and re-used it for subsequent frames.

Answer (score 1):

The host registration process (which involves CUDA interacting with the operating system) is costly in terms of time spent.  As a rule of thumb, it may cost as much in time as the time spent transferring the data (once), effectively doubling the time spent transferring the data, the first time the buffer is used.

Therefore, from a performance perspective alone, registering a buffer and using it once is rarely a significant performance win (you may still wish to do it, however, to enable other things like concurrency).

If a buffer will be used repeatedly, pinning (i.e. registering) the buffer is often a performance win, where the benefit increases with the level of reuse of the buffer, compared to pinning a single contiguous region and using it once.  However this doesn't take into consideration the cost of copying the data to and from the pinned buffer, if that will be necessary.

The benefits here, if any, of pinnning, will vary depending on your specific usage pattern, and exactly what form of usage you will be comparing it to.  However, to repeat, pinning a buffer and using it exactly once is rarely a significant performance win, compared to using non-pinned memory in the transfer.