# Is it safe to use cudaHostRegister on only part of an allocation?

Tags: cuda

I have a C++ class container that allocates, lets say, 1GB of memory of plain objects (e.g. built-ins).

I need to copy *part* of the object to the GPU.
To accelerate and simplify the transfer I want to register the CPU memory as non-pageable ("pinning"), e.g. with `cudaHostRegister(void*, size, ...)` before copying.

(This seems to be a good way to copy further subsets of the memory with minimal logic. For example if plain cudaMemcpy is not enough.)

**Is it safe to pass a pointer that points to only *part* of the original allocated memory, for example a contiguous 100MB subset of the original 1GB.**

I may want to register only part because of efficiency, but also because deep down in the call trace I might have lost information of the original allocated pointer.

In other words, can the pointer argument to `cudaHostRegister` be the something else other than an allocated pointer? in particular an arithmetic result deriving from allocated memory, but still within the allocated range.

It seems to work but I don't understand if, in general, "pinning" part of an allocation can corrupt somehow the allocated block.

---

UPDATE: My concern is that allocation is actually mentioned in the [documentation for the `cudaHostRegister` flag options](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1ge8d5c17670f16ac4fc8fcb4181cb490c):

> - **cudaHostRegisterDefault**: On a system with unified virtual addressing, the memory will be both mapped and portable. On a system
>   with no unified virtual addressing, the memory will be neither mapped
>   nor portable.
> - **cudaHostRegisterPortable**: The memory returned by this call will be considered as pinned memory by all CUDA contexts, not just the one
>   that performed the **allocation**.
> - **cudaHostRegisterMapped**: Maps the **allocation** into the CUDA address space. The device pointer to the memory may be obtained by calling
>   cudaHostGetDevicePointer().
> - **cudaHostRegisterIoMemory**: The passed memory pointer is treated as pointing to some memory-mapped I/O space, e.g. belonging to a
>   third-party PCIe device, and it will marked as non cache-coherent and
>   contiguous.
> - **cudaHostRegisterReadOnly**: The passed memory pointer is treated as pointing to memory that is considered read-only by the device. On
>   platforms without cudaDevAttrPageableMemoryAccessUsesHostPageTables,
>   this flag is required in order to register memory mapped to the CPU as
>   read-only. Support for the use of this flag can be queried from the
>   device attribute cudaDeviceAttrReadOnlyHostRegisterSupported. Using
>   this flag with a current context associated with a device that does
>   not have this attribute set will cause cudaHostRegister to error with
>   cudaErrorNotSupported.

Comment: very little cuda experience here, but sounds fine to me. If you own a block of contiguous memory, a pointer to anywhere in that block (via pointer arithmetic, for example) is valid. You're worried that pinning the memory will invalidate that?

Comment: @yano, yes, I am worried about that or anything else that can go wrong.

Comment: only if there's some cuda wonkiness. Nothing I can think of in C or C++ where this would be a problem. Contiguous memory is the key, but you've already stipulated that. Have you experimented and are seeing problems?

Comment: @yano, no, it works so far. Although, I tested it from a single thread and I am passing only the basic ReadOnly flag (it is a const source for copying).

Comment: @yano look at my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it safe to pass a pointer that points to only part of the original allocated memory, for example a contiguous 100MB subset of the original 1GB.

While I agree that the documentation could be clearer, I think the answer to the question is 'Yes'.

Here's why: The alternative interpretation would be that only whole memory sections returned by, say, `malloc` should be allowed to be registered. However, this is unworkable, because `malloc` could, behind the scenes, have one big section allocated, and only give the user parts of it. So even if you (the user) were `cudaHostRegister`ing those sections returned by `malloc`, they'd actually be fragments of some bigger previously allocated chunk of memory anyway.

By the way, Linux has a similar kernel call to lock memory called [`mlock`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html). It accepts arbitrary memory ranges.

---

One of the other answers claimed (until this test was posted):

> If you need to copy the part-of-the-object just once to the GPU - there's no use in using cudaHostRegister(), because it will likely itself copy the data, physically, elsewhere - so you won't be saving anything

But this is incorrect: registering is worth it, if the chunk of memory being copied is big enough, even if the copying is done only once. I'm seeing about a 2x speed-up with this code (comment out the line indicated), or about 50% if unregistering is also done between the timers.

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

int main()
{
    std::size_t giga = 1024*1024*1024;
    std::vector<char> src(giga, 3);
    char* dst = 0;
    if(cudaMalloc((void**)&dst, giga)) return 1;

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    auto t0 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    if(cudaHostRegister(src.data() + src.size()/2, giga/8, cudaHostRegisterDefault)) return 1; // comment out this line
    if(cudaMemcpy(dst, src.data() + src.size()/2, giga/8, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)) return 1;

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    auto t1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    
    auto d = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t1 - t0).count();
    std::cout << (d / 1e6) << " seconds" << std::endl;
    // un-register and free
}
```

Comment: 1. I've taken back the part you quoted. 2. You're registering on page boundaries.

Comment: @einpoklum *"You're registering on page boundaries."* -- I tried adding 512, and it makes very little difference. It just needs to lock 1 more page than it would otherwise.

Comment: I observe the same thing, registering pays off (and by a lot, ~x100) if the true copied data (host->device) is highly strided. In my case registering first does a coarse job and the fine job is done by a cuda kernel or thrust algorithm accesing the cpu pinned memory. There is an intermediate case which is to *allocate* pinned memory to use as an intermediate buffer. This is about x20 worst than registering (in part because of the allocation and in part because I have to run the first copy on the CPU), but I have to use it for non-trivial types.

Comment: Having said that, a better timing should contain a final memory `cudaHostUnregister(src.data() + src.size()/2)`. Presumably one want to unpin memory once it was used for copying.

Comment: @alfC Indeed, unregistering memory makes the gain slimmer here, but still it's faster to register/unregister in my tests.

Comment: Acording to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54494449/225186, `cudaHostRegister` rarely pays for a single copy, however it also says that it can enable concurrency (in general, not in your example in particular). I think this is the case I am seeing in my tests with strided data.

Comment: @alfC Robert, of course, knows what he's talking about, but "rarely" and "significant" leave room for exceptions and "insignificant gains". Also the runtime libraries and the OS may have improved since then.

Comment: @alfC My test code was actually motivated by the claim that there was some physical copying happening under the hood (which I would have been surprised by).

Comment: Yes, I am not expert, I don't know how pin works. I think it is used with different meanings in different contexts (e.g. MPI pinned memory). Yes, copy is not what is happening, I tried allocating pinned memory and copying to that at it is much slower, although it might be because the copy doesn't use concurrency. Another possibility was that "pages" were copied and that that was faster than normal copies because all the power of the operating system is put in there. The third case, as you seem to imply is that (the whole) page is simply "marked" as pinned, not trivial but still the best option

Comment: Not sure about the exact workings. The decision, whether copying is needed, could also depend on whether the pages the memory block consists of, are physically continuous, or not. Please correct, if totally wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This is a rule-of-thumb answer rather than a proper one:

When the CUDA documentation does not guarantee something is guaranteed to work - you'll need to assume it doesn't. Because if it does happen to work - for you, right now, on the system you have - it might stop working in the future; or on another system; or in another usage scenario.

More specifically - memory pinning happens at page resolution, so unless the part you want to pin starts and ends on a physical page boundary, the CUDA driver will need to pin some more memory before and after the region you asked for - which it could do, but it's going an extra mile to accommodate you, and I doubt that would happen without documentation.

I also suggest you file a bug report via developer.nvidia.com , asking that they clarify this point in the documentation. My experience is that there's... something like a 50% chance they'll do something about such a bug report.

Finally - you could just try it: Write a program which copies to the GPU with and without the pinning of the part-of-the-region, and see whether there's a throughput difference.

Comment: This post along with the [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69505673/12695027) is being discussed on meta in [My answer included a critique of another answer, which has since been edited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412131/my-answer-included-a-critique-of-another-answer-which-has-since-been-edited)

Comment: Yes, I tried copying without pinning first. The problem with that is that I have to use many calls to cudaMemcpy/2D/3D or use thrust which seems to end up doing a lot of element by element copies. Coarse grained pinning allows me to put all the copying logic in a cuda kernel o gpu parallelized thrust algorithm. Having said that, my case is quite specific, data is relatively  compact but internally strided and elements are POD. Outside this case is hard to make pinning help I guess because I would need to pin a lot of memory or many chunks.

Comment: @alfC: You never _have_ to use thrust for anything... thrust itself is completely in user-space and utilizes the same APIs you might. Regardless - strided copy might be a different story than non-strided copy.

Comment: I understand your point. I am just saying what I may end up doing and also how thrust might end up doing things internally. Yes, complicated multidimensional strides copy is the back story here and it is very different than contiguous copy. I guess after all, efficient copy between memory spaces of slightly complicated objects  is just a mirage. Serialization (encoding in contiguous memory in allocated buffers) or universal memory are the only true options really.  Anything else is patches after patches.