# Cuda multi-device asynchronicity with pageable memory

Tags: c++, cuda, openmp

Does Cuda offer a mean to obtain asynchronicity between different devices using pageable memory on the host ? (note that this is *not* about the never-ending questions about blocking `cudaMemcpyAsync` on pageable memory on a single device)

Here is the background: having access to a node with several Cuda devices, I batch my workload to be distributed evenly among all devices. A batch consists in `num_devices` instances (one for each device) of a `cudaMemcpyAsync` from host to device, followed by a kernel launch, and finally a `cudaMemcpyAsync` from device to host. These `num_devices` instances are launched from a `for` loop over devices. But the issue is the following one: since the host memory that I use is pageable, the `cudaMemcpyAsync` are synchronous with the host, and thus each iteration in the innermost `for` loop occurs if-and-only-if the previous one is fully finished, thus preventing devices to all work at the same time.

I am attaching a minimal example below:

```cpp
/*
Compilation: nvcc main.cu -o main.cuda
(nvcc version 12)
*/
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cassert>

// trivial kernel for illustration
__global__
void kernel(double* d_u, const uint64_t size)
{
    uint64_t j = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (j<size) {
        d_u[j] *= 2.0;
    }
}

// providing home-made popcnt in case __builtin_popcount is not supported
unsigned int hm_popcnt(int word) {
    unsigned int n = 0;
    while(word) {
        if (word&1) {++n;}
        word>>=1;
    }
    return n;
}


int main() {

    unsigned int n = 30;
    uint64_t dimension = (1ULL)<<n;

    unsigned int n0 = 27;
    uint64_t batch_size = (1ULL)<<n0;

    int blockSize = 256;
    int numBlocks = (batch_size + blockSize - 1)/blockSize;

    int num_devices;
    cudaGetDeviceCount(&num_devices);
    assert(num_devices!=1); // 1 device, no luck
    assert(__builtin_popcount(num_devices)==1); // for sake of simplicity
    //assert(hm_popcnt(num_devices)==1);

    cudaStream_t streams[num_devices];
    for (int dev_id=0; dev_id<num_devices; ++dev_id) {
        cudaSetDevice(dev_id);
        cudaStreamCreateWithFlags(&streams[dev_id], cudaStreamNonBlocking);
    }

    std::vector<double> h_v(dimension, 1.0); // pageable memory

    // each device holds its array of dimension <batch_size>
    double * d_v[num_devices];
    for (int dev_id=0; dev_id<num_devices; ++dev_id) {
        cudaSetDevice(dev_id);
        cudaMalloc((void**)&d_v[dev_id], batch_size*sizeof(double));
    }

    uint32_t num_batches = ((1UL)<<(n-n0))/num_devices;

    for (uint32_t i=0; i<num_batches; ++i) {
        for (int dev_id=0; dev_id<num_devices; ++dev_id) {
            cudaSetDevice(dev_id);
            uint64_t start_index = (i*num_devices + dev_id) * batch_size;
            cudaMemcpyAsync(d_v[dev_id], &h_v[start_index], batch_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, streams[dev_id]);
            kernel<<<numBlocks, blockSize, 0, streams[dev_id]>>>(d_v[dev_id], batch_size);
            cudaMemcpyAsync(&h_v[start_index], d_v[dev_id], batch_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, streams[dev_id]);
            // h_v is on pageable memory, so the cudaMemcpyAsync is synchronous, preventing devices to work at the same time
        }
    }

    for (int dev_id=0; dev_id<num_devices; ++dev_id)
    {
        cudaSetDevice(dev_id);
        cudaFree(d_v[dev_id]);
        cudaStreamDestroy(streams[dev_id]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Since `dimension` is very large in the productive environment, it is not an option to perform a host-to-host copy from pageable to pinned memory. Instead, I can solve this issue by swapping the outer- and inner-loops, and using an OpenMP `for` loop on the devices (at the price of involving `num_devices` CPU threads, which is fine):

```cpp
// requires to add #include "omp.h" and to compile with flags -Xcompiler -fopenmp
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static, 1) num_threads(num_devices)
for (int dev_id=0; dev_id<num_devices; ++dev_id) {
    cudaSetDevice(dev_id);
    for (uint32_t i=0; i<num_batches; ++i) {
        uint64_t start_index = (i*num_devices + dev_id) * batch_size;
        cudaMemcpyAsync(d_v[dev_id], &h_v[start_index], batch_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, streams[dev_id]);
        kernel<<<numBlocks, blockSize, 0, streams[dev_id]>>>(d_v[dev_id], batch_size);
        cudaMemcpyAsync(&h_v[start_index], d_v[dev_id], batch_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, streams[dev_id]);
    }
}
```

IMO this isn't very elegant, and somehow I feel that Cuda should be offering something cleaner to achieve multi-device asynchronicity in this simple scenario. Is that the case ?
If not, are there other solutions ?

Comment: Threading (irrespective of which framework to use for that) seems to be the right call. The GPU's are not synchronous, but the host is with itself if there is only one thread, so I don't agree that this is a problem that the CUDA API needs to solve.

Comment: Have a for-loop issue the `cudaMemcpyAsync` H->D operations.  Then have another for-loop issue the kernel calls.  Then have another for-loop issue the `cudaMemcpyAsync` D->H operations.  You can then witness overlap/concurrency of the kernels.  Each of those 3 innermost for-loops will need to have a `cudaSetDevice` call first, of course.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I think OP is specifically asking about the H->D copy being asynchronous. Your proposal would still have the kernel on GPU 1 waiting for the H->D of GPU N.

Comment: FYI: [Is it safe to use cudaHostRegister on only part of an allocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69498286/10107454)

Comment: Perhaps.  In my view, the question states: " thus preventing devices to all work at the same time.".  Below the provided answer, OP states: "but about having multiple devices working at the same time.".  My suggestion allows multiple devices to work at the same time, without the OMP or thread refactoring.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Fair enough. One would certainly hope that the kernel has significantly more runtime than the data transfers. But using threading for multi-GPU is quite a typical pattern as can be seen in [NVIDIA/multi-gpu-programming-models](https://github.com/NVIDIA/multi-gpu-programming-models), so I think the answer to the last paragraph should be that threading is the right way of going about this, the right tool in the box.

Comment: OP is already aware of the threading option, so I don't have anything to add there.

Comment: @paleonix thanks for your messages. Ok I take back my initial feeling that the Cuda API should solve this. So it seems that the cpu-threading is the way to go. RobertCrovella, thanks for the non-threading suggestion. But indeed, as suspected by paleonix, the kernel runtime is a fraction of the cumulated H->D + D->H runtime.

Comment: I actually suspected/hoped otherwise because in this case it is always questionable if you wouldn't be better of using the CPU. It sounds like you might want to try sending the data to the GPUs in smaller fragments to get better overlap then.

Answer (score 1):

As you use pageable and not pinned memory, the cudaMemcpyAsync function blocks the calling thread, similar to the cudaMemcpy function. So, indeed, you have to call the cudaMemcpy or cudaMemcpyAsync from different threads to achieve pseudo-asynchronicity between devices.
The caveat here is that this is not an asynchronous copy at all. The CPU thread and GPU are blocked during the copy.

If you want an async copy, you have to use pinned memory - there is no way around it.
You could simply replace the allocation of the pageable memory
`std::vector<double> h_v(dimension, 1.0); // pageable memory`
with a call to [cudaMallocHost()](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/html/group__CUDART__HIGHLEVEL_ge439496de696b166ba457dab5dd4f356.html) in your code!

If you only want to achieve asynchronicity between devices and not async copies between host and devices, your solution is already viable. In this case, you should replace cudaMemcpyAsync with cudaMemcpy.

Comment: only your last § is relevant here. As I mentioned, my question is **not** about single-device asynchronicity between kernel launches and mem copies, but about having multiple devices working at the same time. Although the topic of the max amount of pinned memory does not seem to be solved (e.g., [max-pinned](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/max-amount-of-host-pinned-memory-available-for-allocation/56053)), here using pinned memory seems dangerous since the host array is O(200GB). Last, `cudaMemcpyAsync` behaves as `cudaMemcpy` for pageable memory so only verbosity could be spared.

Comment: I think you have a misconception of the cudaMemcpyAsync function. Also, if you copy data thread-wise, you won't gain any performance improvements from it as you are bound by the bus - yes, your host, too. Probably, the performance/bandwidth decreases because of thread context switches. So you're better off handling the copies sequentially or - in case you have an NVlink - have one target GPU and distribute the data to others.